# C++ combo box Item with value winapi

Tags: c++, winapi, combobox

The following code working successfully, but what i want how to pass the value to each item

//create Combox box

```
hWndComboBox = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "Combobox", NULL,WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|CBS_DROPDOWNLIST , 20, 20, 200, 200, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_MEDIA_SERVER, NULL, NULL);
```

//Adding Item

```
SendMessage(hWndComboBox, CB_ADDSTRING, 1 , (LPARAM)(LPCTSTR)"Item1");
SendMessage(hWndComboBox, CB_ADDSTRING, 2 , (LPARAM)(LPCTSTR)"Item2");
SendMessage(hWndComboBox, CB_ADDSTRING, 3 , (LPARAM)(LPCTSTR)"Item3");
```

//Function

```
case IDC_MEDIA_SERVER:
{
    switch(HIWORD(wParam))
    {
        case CBN_DROPDOWN:
            break;
        case BN_CLICKED:
            break;
        case CBN_SELCHANGE:
            int idx_row;
            char strText[255] = {0};
            idx_row = SendMessage(hWndComboBox , CB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0 );
            SendMessage(hWndComboBox,CB_GETLBTEXT, idx_row,(LPARAM)strText);
            MessageBox(0,strText,"Information", MB_OK | MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
            break;
    }
}
break;
```

How to get the selected item value???

Comment: You're going to need considerably more clarification than the single sentence you provided. It makes no sense, doesn't describe a problem, nor does it ask a *question*. You can add text to your combo box. Now what?

Comment: I have downvoted, because it is unclear what you are asking. First you asked *how to pass the value to each item*, **and based on your edit**, seems that you have solved your problem. You should have edited your question to reflect that. Now you ask *How to get the selected item value???* but seems to me that you managed to solve that too. If that is the case, you should mention this in your edit, if it is not, then describe what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

1. use the `TEXT()` macro instead of type-casting `char[]` literals to `LPCTSTR`:

   ```
   SendMessage(hWndComboBox, CB_ADDSTRING, 1, (LPARAM)TEXT("Item1"));
   SendMessage(hWndComboBox, CB_ADDSTRING, 2 , (LPARAM)TEXT("Item2"));
   SendMessage(hWndComboBox, CB_ADDSTRING, 3 , (LPARAM)TEXT("Item3"));
   ```
2. declare `strText[]` as `TCHAR` instead of char`:

   ```
   case CBN_SELCHANGE:
   {
       TCHAR strText[255] = {0};
       int idx_row = SendMessage(hWndComboBox, CB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0 );
       SendMessage(hWndComboBox, CB_GETLBTEXT, idx_row, (LPARAM)strText);
       MessageBox(0, strText, TEXT("Information"), MB_OK | MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
       break;
   }
   ```